# Solr 8.11.2 Mapping Char Filter gives no output in admin panel

Tags: solr

recently updated from Solr 5.* version to Solr 8.11.2, while testing the functionality I came across a "bug" or I'm not even sure what it is, in admin panel MCF row is missing input data.

After understanding that it's not working I made a super easy configuration:

This is my mapping file:

"a" => "b"
"d" => "c"

This is config in schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="text_general_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The problem with this is that when I connect to admin panel, choose core, select Analyzer, uncheck the verbose output and select text_general_ws it tokenizes the text okay, the a's are changed to b's and d's are changed to c's, but in the "MCF" row I don't get ANY output, when in 5.* solr I was getting the same text that was in the input but only with changed letters if any was there to change.

Would appriciate any help :)

[Screenshot of not having ANYTHING in MCF row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOv9I.jpg)